# does mechanize python library have the ability to wait until javascript has dynamically loaded content before getting the page contents

Tags: javascript, python, dynamic

I would like to scrape a site which dynamically loads content using javascript.

I would like to scrape the content the javascript loads.

I know there are ways of getting the javascript to load (ghost or pywt4 webkit) however I have not been able to get pyqt4 installed and recognised by my ipython installation.

Therefore since I was using requests (and have used mechanize) does requests have the ability to scrape a pages content after javascript has finished dynamically loading page content (i.e. divs, img, href, links etc)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, mechanize does not support that, but there is an easy way of doing it with [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.set_window_size(100000, 200000)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(5) # wait to load

# now print the response
print driver.page_source
```

You will have to install Firefox too in this case.

Comment: can driver.page_source then be used in a parser like beautifulsoup?

Comment: Aparently selenium is slow when compared to 1) ghost.py and 2) pyqt4 webkit (headless browser) have you found this to be the case? Selenium might be a good option, since I cant get 1) and 2) above to work - pyqt4 won't install.

Comment: my script and all my libraries are configured in python 2.7 can you use selenium with that -it took forever to get all these libraries working in 2.7

Comment: driver.page_source works, however I have tried to put it into beautifulsoup soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source) but this doesn't work. Many Thanks.

Comment: I have used `driver.page_source` several times on Beautifulsoup before, what's the error you get ?